# $R$ module homomorphisms from $(x,y) \to k[x,y]/(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the trivial map the only $R=k[x,y]$-module homomorphism $\phi:(x,y) \to k[x,y]/(x,y)$? Where $(x,y)$ is the principal ideal generated by $x,y$.

I am trying to see why this might be the case, but I am very confused. I am trying to decide where I might have to send $x,y$. It is difficult for me to work this out since $1 \notin (x,y)$.

Comment: What does $\phi : (x, y) \to k[x, y] / (x, y)$ mean?

Comment: @MarkSaving hey mark. Just an arbitrary $R$-module homomorphism.

Comment: @MarkSaving oh the principal ideal generated by $(x,y)$.

Comment: Oh, do you mean that $(x, y)$ is the ideal of $k[x, y]$ generated by $x$ and $y$? I was rather confused, but this makes sense.

Comment: @MarkSaving yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(x, y)$ is a finitely presented $R$-module. The presentation consists of two generators $a$ and $b$ together with the governing equation that $y \cdot a = x \cdot b$.

Therefore, $\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$we have that $\Hom((x, y), M) \cong \{(a, b) \in M^2 \mid y \cdot a = x \cdot b\}$ for all modules $M$.

In particular, for $k[x, y] / (x, y)$, we have that $y \cdot a = 0 = x \cdot b$, so we have that $\Hom((x, y), M) \cong (k[x, y] / (x, y))^2\} \cong k^2$. So there are a great many homomorphisms of this form.